# groupby pandas by prioritizing text from another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this (snippet) df:

```
     date   type
0   200101  SN2
1   200102  SN2
2   200102  LS8
3   200102  SN1
4   200103  SN2
```

I would like to group it using `pandas` by the `date` column and the value in column `type` needs to follow this rule: LS8>SN2>SN1. The solution I came up with is to add a letter before each type that represents the rule e.g., a_LS8, b_SN2, c_SN1. That way I can sort the df according to the date and type, and then do `df.groupby(by='date').first()`. Then to remove this extra letter. The desired outcome will be:

```
    date    type
0   200101  SN2
1   200102  LS8
2   200103  SN2
```

Is there a better way to perform that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), so then is possible aggregate by `min`:

```
df['type'] = pd.Categorical(df['type'], categories=['LS8','SN2','SN1'], ordered=True)

df1 = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['type'].min()
print (df1)
     date type
0  200101  SN2
1  200102  LS8
2  200103  SN2
```

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware of this possibility, thank you